# Prevent locking table when displayed in subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table that gets populated with a couple queries.  When that table is opened, it becomes locked and the queries will not function.  I figured to avoid having people open the table directly to view the data, I'd display the table in a datasheet view in a form with the recordset snapshot (which i've done already) but even displaying it here locks it. I can't see any combination of settings that prevents this table from getting locked.  If the datasheet property is Locked:Yes, it can't be manually edited but the table itself gets locked and the query won't update it.  If i change the properties to Locked:No, it still locks the table anyway and the queries still fail (but the data is editable within the subform?!).  Any idea how I can display this table without locking it?

The form does contain another datasheet that i need to remain editable

Comment: This appears to be a design, not code issue. Since issue is not reproducible and there is no code provided for analysis, question is really not appropriate for SO.

Comment: What is the forms locking settings in the data tab? The setting you want to look at is Record-locks. You can set this to none, edited record, or the table.

Comment: @Albert for both the form and the subform, the Record Locks is set to No Locks

Comment: Well, base the form on a the table - not a query. Are you sure the query allows updates? Can you open the query directly and then edit data when you do so? So perhaps the query does not allow updates - and it not record locking at all?

Comment: @Albert thanks for the ideas.  I think I wasn't perfectly clear with the scenario; the form holds a few buttons for VBA scripts, as well as two sub forms each displaying a datasheet of another table.  The query will only run when called in the VBA.  The query will fail to run if the table in question is locked.  The table is locked when the table is simply opened to view.  The table will also be locked if opened to view by way of displaying the datasheet in a subform.

Comment: I can open the table and edit directly.  But that's also something I don't care to do (or want others to be able to do).  So, if there's a way for example to open a table without allowing to edit, forcing it to not "lock" others out, then I feel like that would also apply to my scenario with the subform.

Comment: Only suggested to open table based on the SAME data source the form is based on. Not a suggestion for users to work that way, but ONLY for you to be 100% sure that the data source can be edited. it not clear if you using a default datasheet, or you created a form as a datasheet and are using that. I would in fact double check the settings on that sub form datasheet in design mode - and make 100% sure that the locks are sent to none. As a general simple rule, no lock should be occurring here. Can you run that test update code without the datasheet open - and does that work?

Comment: @Albert opening the source table directly is editable yes.  Checked again; parent form is 100% record locks: no locks.  Subform actually only has "Locked" Yes/No, and is "No".  This might be relevant info: the first query that's run is a Make Table query which would delete existing contents of the table (desired).  So having the source table open and attempting to run this query (forgetting about the forms) generates the error that it "could not lock".  If the source table is in that subform, displayed, it creates the same "lock" and the query can't be run...